# Reducing a 4th order differential equation to a second order one

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a fourth order linear differential equation which I am trying to solve:
$$
r^3 ( 2 + r^2 ) [r^2 f(r)]'''' + 4 r^2 ( 1 + r^2 ) [r^2 f(r)]''' - r ( 10 + 7 r^2 ) [r^2 f(r)]''  + ( 10 - r^2 ) [r^2 f(r)]' = P(r) .
$$
$P(r)$ is a source term whose exact form I already know. I also know that the general solution to this equation is of the form
\begin{align}
f(r) &= {\tilde f}(r) + c_1 ( 2 + r^2 )  + \frac{c_2}{r^2}  + c_3 r^{\sqrt{5}-1} \,_2F_1\bigg( \frac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{2} , \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} , 1 + \sqrt{5} ; - \frac{r^2}{2} \bigg)\\
&\qquad \qquad  + c_4 r^{-\sqrt{5}-1} \,_2F_1\bigg( \frac{-3-\sqrt{5}}{2} , \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} , 1 - \sqrt{5} ; - \frac{r^2}{2} \bigg) . 
\end{align}
where ${\tilde f}(r)$ is a particular solution to the equation.

Now, due to other considerations, I am only interested in solutions which have a well-defined Laurent expansion near $r=0$. In particular, this implies that I am not interested in the hypergeometric functions above. Suppose I have chosen my particular solution ${\tilde f}(r)$ so that it has a Laurent expansion at $r=0$, then the solution that I am interested in has the form
\begin{align}
f(r) &= {\tilde f}(r) + c_1 ( 2 + r^2 )  + \frac{c_2}{r^2}.
\end{align}
The differential equation for this type of solution is
$$
\left[ \frac{[ r^2 f(r) ]'}{r(1+r^2)}  \right]' = P_1(r)
$$
Would it be possible to determine the source $P_1(r)$ directly from $P(r)$?